# Kinematics simple question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, relative-motion

Question: In order to protect himself from the rain, a person is standing holding an umbrella at right angle to the horizontal surface. The rain is falling at 10m/s when the velocity of the wind is zero. Suddenly, wind begins to blow at a speed of 20m/s, towards 30 degrees south of west. Now by what angle does the person have to turn his umbrella in order to protect himself from the rain?

What I did:
Split the speed of wind into components:
$$v(x) = 20\cos30$$
$$v(y) = 20\sin30 + 10$$

Thus, I found the angle that the resulting rain makes with the vertical:
$$\tan\theta = \frac{10\sqrt{3}}{20} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\theta = \arctan\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

However, the answer is given to be $\arctan2$, where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the 30 degrees are the inclination on the horizontal plane, so you need to consider only the vertical inclination:
$\upsilon_x = 20 $ $\upsilon_y = 10$ 
$$\theta = \arctan \frac{rise}{run} = \arctan \frac{\upsilon_y}{\upsilon_x} = \arctan \frac{1}{2}$$ 
that is the angle from the horizontal, you'll probably need the complementary angle
$\theta^* = 90 - \theta = 90 - \arctan(1/2)$, a special property of $\arctan$ is that  $\arctan(1/x) = 90 -\arctan(x)$ so $$\theta^* = \arctan{2}$$

Comment: I don't get it, sorry, could you explain it again please? Why won't you split it into components? In order to get the resultant velocity of the rain, wouldn't you split the wind into components along the plane of the rain?

Comment: This can be thought of as a 3-dimensional problem. The wind is in the plane parallel to the ground and the rain is falling perpendicular to it. So, resolving the wind velocity into components parallel to the rain should give a zero. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @tpb261 I don't understand, I'm afraid. Why would you complicate it into a 3 dimensional problem when it is only in two dimensions? As the rain is perpendicular to ground, resolving the vectors of the wind along the axis of the ground and rain can easily be done using the 30 degree angle given. As it is thirty degrees south of west, it is making a thirty degree angle with the ground, which is assumed to be horizontal.

Comment: @Gummy_bears The fact is that to solve this problem you don't care if the wind is blowing on your left or your right, in this case 30° south of west. Because if it blows on your left and you turn left, the wind will blow on your face! So, you only need the inclination on the vertical axis! You don't care about the angle on the horizontal plane, only the angle on the vertical plane! You don't have to split into componenents cause you already have the two components $\upsilon_y$ and $\upsilon_x$, and to determine the angle, you proceed as showed.